# Ajax call (post/get) with Wso2 Indentity server, is that possible

Tags: jsp, wso2, wso2-identity-server

It is literally challenging for me to think of an ajax call to the Wso2 IS services, Is that possible?
To be more specific, I need all the functionalities of travelocity.com(Servlets/filters),
 for SAML-SSO, as an ajax from JS.

Are there any possibilities of RestWebservice?

Comment: i think this would help you out https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/SAML+2.0+Web+SSO

Comment: As it is described, is it must to use IDP? or just sso configuration is enough?

Comment: must use IDP? aCan you explain more please.

Comment: In Management console, isn't it enough to register the application with Saml2SSO & OAuth2 if required, do we need to configure IDP(Identity Provider ) too ?

Comment: hmm... unless you want federated authentication like Google, Yahoo etc. you don't need to configure an IDP

Comment: Thanks @farasath . Just cleared what I need, looking into the websso.. Hopefully this is what I am looking for, working on it..

Comment: posted the link as an answer in case someone else would need the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the relevant details [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/SAML+2.0+Web+SSO).
Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932541/wso2is-skip-authenticationendpoint-login-do) for more details as well.

Comment: the above can be refered, useful for unerstanding, but acceptable answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932541/wso2is-skip-authenticationendpoint-login-do/40935980?noredirect=1#comment69101913_40935980