# Wso2IS skip authenticationendpoint/login.do

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Using java client, I have generated the SAMLRequest string
Is there a way to post the whole data, and skip the IdentityServer login page?
With the data which I pass, has to meet the authentication for SSO and then generate Oauth2Token.

Comment: atleast a url to generate saml2 assertion..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [request path authentication](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Basic+Auth+Request+Path+Authentication) and send the username, password in the same request, which will give you the SAML assertion. You can later use SAML2 bearer grant type to exchange that assertion to an oauth token.

Comment: Looks like promising, but unfortunately it retrieves the signin page for the curl request mentioned in that doc.. ! Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: it reaches the screen to approve/not approve/always approve... not the saml response yet..!

Comment: The doc users oauth/oidc as the inbound protocol. Since you are using SAML you need to configure request path authentication (Steps 5-7) in the doc. And send the initial SAML request with the additional parameter 'sectoken' ( `http://host:port/samlsso?SAMLRequest=<SAMLRequest>&sectoken=<base64encode(username:password)>`).

Comment: yes, configured, the step5 &6, then it retreives a screen to approve/deny.. if I click on approve, then it retreives the code, BTW the /samlsso(POST), throws content-not allowed exception. with get it will throw:  Error when processing the authentication request!

Comment: I just checked with post binding to /samlsso with sectoken. And it works. May be you could follow [this document](https://wso2.org/jira/secure/attachment/35472/RequestPathAuthenticator.pdf), with ["travelocity" sample app](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+Single+Sign-On) to and use a tool like [SAML tracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) to understand the flow and update your application accordingly.

Comment: the problem is I can not use jsp/filters .. I have to go like direct post/get etc..

Comment: For this you won't have to. I've added my SAML tracer dump [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eeedf407decc34793b7bba455d397c16). You can have a look at the second http post request. If configured correctly, you'll get response with a html page which has a saml assertion inside. (The 3rd request is posting that same assertion to the ACS). If you are still seeing any error, please post the error log from the IS.

Comment: if samlsso post-binding works, then what will be the response I can expect, similarly, in the answer that you have mentioned. have mentioned, later SAML2 can be used, how to do that with the code in the response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129677/discussion-between-pulasthi7-and-peaceuser).

Comment: What did you put for <SAMLRequest>? @pulasthi7 I have the same problem but I don't know what value you used for SAMLRequest