# What value do I put for SAMLRequest? WSO2 IS Skipping Login.do

Tags: server, wso2, identity

My sectoken is authorized but I don't know how to formulate a URL so that I can bypass the WSO2 IS sign-in page (login.do). 
I read online it can be passed through a link in this format:
localhost:9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest=[SAMLRequest]&sectoken=[SECTOKEN]

I'm just not sure what to put in for [SAMLRequest].

Comment: Could you specify source of the "I read online?"  And SAML request is deflated and encoded XML SAML Request, here is [an example](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_req.php), but you will need to always generate one based on the client and timestamp (it's not a static string)

Comment: @gusto2 Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932541/wso2is-skip-authenticationendpoint-login-do 
It's in the comments of the answer.

Comment: And - what do you want to achieve? If you are already have the username / password (sectoken), it's easier to use password OAuth grant to get an access token.. In this case your application needs to properly generate (and optionally sign) the SAMLRequest

Comment: I want to 'skip' the IS sign-in page because I want to make it so that if you're already logged in on my website, you shouldn't have to login a second time to access the IS. I thought I might also be able to skip it using a cURL request in PHP since through command line I was able to authorize my sec_token. I'm sorry, I'm somewhat new to this but how would I go about using OAuth to get an access token?

Comment: @gusto2 Any ideas? Sorry, I'm really trying to fix this.

Comment: There are many options and you've provided too few information to chees the best option. As you are using PHP I don't know any useful frameworks to create SAMLRequest (simpleSAMLphp could be too big gun for that). What is relation of your app with the WSO2IS? Is the client using APIs? Do you want SSO (single sign-on)?  Cannot you use WSO2IS to authenticate users (instead of on your own?) You could as well get an access the token as soon as user authenticates with your appllication (using e.g. OAuth2 password grant)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176357/discussion-between-gusto2-and-saltysea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the answer, you may try to use [OneLogin PHP module](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) to generate a SAML Request.

Here is an [example SAML Authn Request](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_req.php) however you may need to change the issuer, destination, AssertionConsumerURL, and issue timestamp.

Please note there's difference when sending SAML Request as GET and POST. GET (Redirect-Binding) uses deflate and encode, signature is a separate request parameter, POST (POST-Binding) uses signed XML and only encoded XML, not deflated.

SAML is great protocol (very well designed and secure when implemented properly), but it may look difficult for people who hasn't use it before, it may require using external libraries to properly create requests and validate responses. That's why you may be as well looking for option which would may make your life simpler, such as using WSO2IS for SSO (single-sign-on) e.g. using simpleSAMLphp or direct OAuth authorization request.

Comment: Otherwise you can use the IdP initiated flow: `https://localhost:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=<saml-issuer>&sectoken=<sectoken>`

Ref: https://medium.com/@PrakhashS/sp-initiated-sso-and-idp-initiated-sso-in-wso2-is-121e954e8614